# Multi Site magento setup not adding tax to just 1 particular site

Tags: multistore, tax

So i have a single installation of magento running multiple websites. All of my stores except for 1 all display the tax correctly. I just have 1 though that does not add tax at all. all the sites have the default site settings but its just 1 that doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas? ive tried to comb through everything and even contacted my hosting company who also couldn't find any settings that were wrong.

ive checked all the tax on products. I have the same product across all the sites so i used that as my test product. It brings up tax on 6 of my sites but not on 1 and all the settings are set to the default installation of magento which is working properly. It was the 3rd multistore i set up out of 7 which is why i find it weird because they all have the same settings....

i was thinking maybe its something in the database i could check. does anyone know which table in the database controls the tax class per site to see if it had a different value than the rest of the sites.

Comment: Just a quick thought - did you check to make sure all the products in that store have the Tax Class set correctly? Would you mind editing your question to list exactly what you have checked so far? Otherwise it's really just a list of "did you check this?".

Comment: yes i went ahead and added to my original post. it is the same exact item  across all my multistore setups and tax works in all but 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i finally figured out what the problem was. i ran the following sql query a long time ago to change all the products to taxable goods:

UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int SET value=2 WHERE attribute_id=121;

obviously for anyone running this query you will need to make sure "121" is the correct attribute for your database...you can find out by running:

SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code LIKE 'tax_class_id';

and for some reason it never changed that ones store products to taxable goods. I ran it a second time just to make sure and it seemed to change all the products for every store to taxable goods and now everything works fine and tax is charged for all sites.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so default Magento is US style taxes.  So you don't see tax until you checkout for an address that has both a rate and is included in a valid tax rule.

Is this a clean install?

Can you upload a screen shot of your tax configuration screen, a screen shot of your tax rules screen, and a screen shot of the cart that your estimating shipping costs for (that should show taxes)?

Thanks,
Chuck